# How to again receive an invitation to be a "Recognized member" of a Collective

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

***Preamble:** I'm posting this question following the advice of the SO support ("Generally, the best way to get possible bugs with Collectives seen is to post it on Stack Overflow's meta, which hosts questions and issues about the software. That way, other users and our developers can vet the problem and discuss any solutions or other potential problems.")*

I recently contacted the support because, a couple of days ago I received an invitation to become a "Recognized member" of the [Google Cloud Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=members&ActiveRole=AllRoles&Page=1). After having accepted the invitation by clicking on the corresponding button it appeared that my membership to the Collective was canceled. Not only my profile was not changed to "Recognized member", but my membership to the Collective was cancelled. I don't know if I made any mistake (clicking on a wrong button?), but it is possible.

I joined again the Collective yesterday, hoping the invitation will be displayed again. So far I still don't appear as a Collective member.

So, my question is simple: Is it possible to again receive the invitation to be a "Recognized member" of the Google Cloud Collective?

Comment: Posting here definitely gets the bug recorded, but unless someone already happens to know the answer, this definitely seem like a question for real-deal Support. Meta (presumably) won't be able to do anything about getting your invitation back; staff probably can!

Comment: @zcoop98 Thanks for your comment. I fully understand your point and do agree with you, but as said in the preamble I'm just following the support advice... I even don't know if it is a "bug": I maybe clicked on the wrong button... I just try to find a solution :)

Comment: @zcoop98 Meta is actually where real support (and bugs) are handled (at least some of the time)

Comment: @Catija Sounds good, I apologize for passing on bad advice! I guess I read this more as a  request akin to a password reset or account retrieval, both of which usually get relegated to the Contact Us portal rather than sorted out on Meta. Do you know if Collectives will use Meta.SO as an official support channel like Teams does going forward?

Comment: Yes, @zcoop98. Collectives is an official feature of Stack Overflow. All official features of Stack Overflow use Meta Stack Overflow as their official support channel. The [[meta-tag:collectives]] tag will be used to indicate that the question/bug report/support ticket/whatever is specifically about Collectives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! There was indeed a bug that made the link break. This bug is fixed now and you should've received a new invitation from the collective.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it works now! I think I've detected another problem: after having accepted the invitation, the Collective home page shows a block titled with "Welcome, .... You’re now a Recognized Member for this collective. Here’s how to get started now". In this block we see a sub-block titled "Recommend an answer" with text starting by "Help users find the best answer...". The link on "Help users" does not work. The page shows `[object Object]`.

Comment: Thanks @Renaud Tarnec, I'm not seeing the exact same issue as you but that link isn't going to the right place currently. I've logged a bug with the developers to fix the link.